# How can I see what my app is sending to the internet

Tags: android

I am using a thirdpart SDK in my app and I want to see exactly what it is sending back to the SDK provider.

There is no debug info coming back in logcat from this SDK. how can I see what it is sending in eclipse or on my device?

Comment: do you have the source code?

Answer (score 1):

If you can load your app on an emulator you can use tools like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

The other option is to have your actual device rooted: then you can use apps like [NetworkLog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.networklog) or [Shark](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lv.n3o.shark&feature=search_result).